# Google play publishing apk error

Tags: apk, production

Why is this happening to me. I tried 2 times before but it gives this error on play store

[image: Image of Error]

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: @SLaks I don't see how he could have...

Comment: I attached image file with question.... I didn't updated my sdk. infact I published my game and received an error mail for not publishing error. I removed that bug and uploaded a new apk with version2.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one, very poorly asked question for Stack Overflow.  However, the error is clearly stated in the description.

You're targeting a lower SDK (19) in your new version than your previous version (23) already published and they don't allow that.

Comment: I attached image file with question.... I didn't updated my sdk. infact I published my game and received an error mail for not publishing error. I removed that bug and uploaded a new apk with version2.